# Python loop - stochastic vs batch loop, and why its taking too long?

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Loop 1: (Stochastic - expected faster)

```
 for i in range(len(data)):
        x = data[i]
        for t in range(0, m):
            theta[t] -= my_lambda * (np.dot(theta, x) - y[i]) * x[t]
```

vs Loop 2: (Batch - expected slower)

```
for t in range(0, m):
        temp = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            x = data[i]
            temp += (np.dot(theta, x) - y[i]) * x[t]
        theta[t] = theta[t] - my_lambda * temp / M
```

But my batch is much much much faster - One iteration Elapsed time 0.025356054306
vs my stochastic is really slower - One iteration Elapsed time 1.0576338768

Here my m is 13 and data is around 500 tuples.
Can anyone tell me why so? Or where did I mess up for stochastic?
Thanks!

### EDIT 1:

```
data = [[], [], ...]
data = [record1, record2 ...]
record = [1, x1, x2, ... , x_m]

theta is vector
theta = np.zeros(m+1) //np is numpy
```

Comment: Are you measuring just the loop, or the entire algorithm (where the two approaches may require a different number of iterations to converge)?

Comment: no just loop, one iteration time

Comment: To save us having second-guess the types and dimensions of things, could you come up with a minimal self-contained example that demonstrates the difference in performance?

Comment: @NPE not sure, what you want, but I just did edit, let me know what else should I write? Thanks!

Comment: I mean a complete script that we can experiment with by running it. Ideally something short that clearly demonstrates the problem.